# How to store a value( stored on PHP server variable ) to the extension made on crossrider when it is being installed into browser

Tags: server-variables, crossrider

Is there any way around to store a value( stored on server variable ) to the extension made on crossrider while the user installs the extension to his browser ? This is something when the user initiates the installation of the browser add-on !!

Say a situation like: I am made a browser extension, and display the link to download and install the extension on my website. Now I need to store a value taken from php and store it locally somewhere in the extension which the user can't delete unless uninstalled the extension itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this from within the extension as long as the server variable can be fetched using a URL (e.g. create a php page that simply returns the value of the server variable).

**STEP 1**

---

Depending on whether you need to process the returned data, you can use one of the following approaches to fetch and save the value.

**Note**: I recommend implementing this step in your `background.js` file so that it executes ONLY once when the extension first runs.

**Method 1** [*Response does not require processing*]: Use the [appAPI.db.setFromRemote()](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db-method-setFromRemote) method to fetch and save the value.

```
var serverVar = appAPI.db.get('serverVar');
if (!serverVar) {
    appAPI.db.setFromRemote(
        "<URL>", // URL to fetch the server variable
        'serverVar' // Name of key to use for saving the value
    );
}
```

**Method 2** [*Response does require processing*]: Use the [appAPI.request.get()](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.request-method-get) method to fetch the value, process the response, and then use the appAPI.db.set() method [For more information, see http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db-method-set] to save the value:

```
var serverVar = appAPI.db.get('serverVar');
if (!serverVar) {
    appAPI.request.get(
        "<URL>", // URL to fetch the server variable
        function(response, headers) { // onSuccess callback function
            // process the reponse as required
            // e.g. trim leading and trailing spaces
            var myProcessedData = response.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '');

            // save data to local db
            appAPI.db.set('serverVar', myProcessedData);
    });
}
```

**STEP 2**

---

Once the server variable is saved to the local database, it can be retrieved from within the extension background scope or page scope using the appAPI.db.get() method [For more information, see http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db-method-get], as follows:

```
var serverVar = appAPI.db.get("serverVar");
```